# error MSB4019: The imported project "..../WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found

Tags: asp.net-web-api, msbuild, continuous-integration, build-server

My web API [project](https://github.com/Team-Glare/CELT2/tree/main/celt2/API) builds fine from Visual Studio. I was trying to setup the CI in the github workflows using below yml.

```
name: web-api-ci-pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    env:
      SOLUTIONPATH: celt2/API/CELTAPI.sln

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 5.0.x
    - name: Build code
      run: dotnet build ${{env.SOLUTIONPATH}}
```

But, in the build step I am getting below error:

> D:\a\CELT2\CELT2\celt2\API\CELTAPI\CELTAPI.csproj(153,3): error
> MSB4019: The imported project
> "C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
> was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration
> "C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
> is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

[image]

[CELTAPI.csproj:](https://github.com/Team-Glare/CELT2/blob/main/celt2/API/CELTAPI/CELTAPI.csproj)

[image]

Can anyone please point me out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: hm, 

I could remember this...long time ago, I think I had a similar problem, which could be solved to check the visual studio build tools correct configured on the build-server. I suggest you check them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are building one of the branches that contain a classic ASP.NET (not ASP.NET Core) project, which is unsupported by the .NET SDK.

If you need to build classic ASP.NET Applications, I recommend using the `setup-msbuild` action instead of `setup-dotnet`https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-msbuild and run `msbuild   -p:Configuration=Release -restore ${{env.SOLUTIONPATH}}` instead